# jquery set input-field to readable

Tags: jquery, html, input

i would to switch an inputfield between readable and readonly. i can set the field to readonly without problems but the other way will not work. Do you know why?

```
$('.infinite_checkbox').live('click', function(e) {      
if ($('#amount_input_'+id).attr("disabled") != true)
  { 
    $('#amount_input_'+id).val('');
    $('#amount_input_'+id).attr("disabled", true); 
  } else {
    $('#amount_input_'+id).attr("disabled", false);
  }
});
```

i have also tried it with .removeAttr("disabled")

thanks for help!

Comment: live got removed on jQuery 1.9 your code won't work when you upgrade jQuery

Comment: check [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PVLMm/)

Answer (score 0):

Well you're not using `readonly`, but `disabled`, but never mind.  Use `.prop()`:

```
$("#amount_input_" + id).prop('disabled', true);
$("#amount_input_" + id).prop('disabled', false);
```

Unrelated but if you're using jQuery 1.7+ change `.live` to use `.on`.

Answer (score 0):

You Can Test This code

```
$('.infinite_checkbox').bind("click",function(In){
   if($(In.target).attr("checked")=="checked"){
      $('#amount_input_'+id).prop("disabled",true);
   }else{
      $('#amount_input_'+id).prop("disabled",false);
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

$('#amount_input_'+id).attr("readonly","");

Comment: A little bit of an explanation on this would be nice.